# How to do this integral of Hypergeometric functions in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I've tried to integrate by part, but it seems that Mathematica is still not able to integrate.

```
Integrate[(24(1-z)^a)/((-1+(1-z)^a)^2z)+(24a(1-z)^(3a) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, 2 - a, 1/z])/((-1+a)(-1+(1-z)^a)^3 (-1+z)z)-(24 a Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1,2+a,1/z])/((1+a)(-1+(1-z)^a)^3 (-1+z)z),z]
```

[image]

We actually know the result exists but we want to get it from this integral.

Is there any commands in Mathematica that are usually helpful in doing integral?

Comment: In general, it can be very useful to provide `Assumptions` to `Integrate`. For instance the range of `a`, or whether it is real and the like. By default, Mathematica assumes the most general scenario which is often not necessary, so that assumptions help to find a (simpler) solution

Comment: One can calculate such an integral for several special values of `a` e.g. `-1/2, 1/2, 3/2`. For `a` integer it is `ComplexInfinity`. What are assumptions on `a`?

Comment: @Artes Even more generally, at half-integer "a"

Comment: @Artes I think 0<a<1

Comment: Even `Integrate[(24 (1 - z)^a)/((-1 + (1 - z)^a)^2 z), z, 
 Assumptions -> 0 < a < 1]` returns unevaluated, so it is not surprising that the full integral does as well.  In fact, this simpler integral returns an answer only for `a` a rational number, and even then typically in terms of `RootSum`.  The only instance of a solution to the full integral that I found was a -> 1/2.